# SSH installation error in Ubuntu running within VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

New to VirtualBox and VM, I am running Ubuntu with 14.04 on latest VirtualBox. I have 2 network adapters:

1. Host-only
2. NAT

I run the following command to install SSH:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

gives this error:

> 'Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

So it cannot connect to the network. Do I have to do any port forwarding?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean you haven't got network connection, it might be that your DNS isn't working. Try: `ping 8.8.8.8`, if this works you have network (and internet) connection,

Comment: Use bridging when setting up your virtual NICs and link them to the physical NIC that has internet access. Then set your VM network accordingly (e.g. DHCP vs. static).

Comment: ping8.8.8.8 gives network unreachable.Being an application developer, and new to network settings, need specific instructions to connect to the network.

Comment: See the link, to understand the theory https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_bridged.html

Comment: look at the image in this link https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=16619

Comment: Bridged networking connects a virtual machine to a network using the host computer's Ethernet adapter. So I added a bridged a adapter in place of the host-only adapter. Now, it is able to connect to internet. And I am able to putty to my VM

Comment: @kakoli I just saw that your question was already resolved using the bridged adapter, so maybe that's good enough for you. But if you want to figure out why your host-only/NAT combo wasn't working, then you might want to add the output of the `ip route` command or of `route -n`. There's a reasonably good chance that there was a routing issue causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you got a "Could not resolve" error suggests that your VM couldn't reach a DNS server. In the comments you say that you can't ping public addresses, which suggests that your VM isn't configured for network access. In my experience the simplest way to have a VirtualBox VM connect to the internet is to use the NAT interface.

You can do this via the GUI, but I'll include command-line examples for concreteness.

First let's remove all of network interface cards (for the sake of simplicity and so that we don't leave any room for a routing conflict):

```bsh
for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do
    vboxmanage modifyvm "${VMNAME}" --nic${n} none
done
```

Now let's add a single NAT interface:

```bsh
vboxmanage modifyvm "${VMNAME}" --nic1 NAT
```

Let's sanity-check the NIC configuration:

```bsh
vboxmanage showvminfo "${VMNAME}" | grep '^NIC'
```

The output should something like this:

```
NIC 1:          MAC: 08002784C3DE, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on,
                Trace: off (file: none), Type: Am79C973, Reported speed: 0
                Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings: MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 2:           disabled
NIC 3:           disabled
NIC 4:           disabled
NIC 5:           disabled
NIC 6:           disabled
NIC 7:           disabled
NIC 8:           disabled
```

Now, if you want, let's add a port-forwarding rule for ssh. Here is an example which maps port 2222 on the host to port 22 on the guest:

```bsh
vboxmanage modifyvm "${VMNAME}" --natpf1 ssh,tcp,,2222,,22
```

Now boot the VM and then we'll test the network connection.

```bsh
vboxmanage startvm "${VMNAME}"
```

Now try to ping a public host. Finally, install your Ubuntu package.